# Property [***] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, slug

I tried doing this for a website but my 'hotel' table has both an 'id' and a 'hotel_id' column. I heard eloquent recognizes the associated table name with _id as the primary key when defining a relationship. How would I define my relationship with the comments to the hotel? I have tried this in my Hotel model

```
public function comments() { return $this->hasMany(Comments::class, 'hotel_id') }
```

this is my controller for the page

```
public function hotelPage($hotel_id)
{
    $hotels = Hotel::select(
        'hotel.hotel_id'
        ,'hotel.name'
        ,'hotel.photo_url'
        ,'hotel.address'
        ,'hotel.desc_en'
        //,'hotel.hotel_url'
        ,DB::raw("(CASE WHEN
            COALESCE(hotel.hotel_url,'')!='' THEN
            LOWER(CONCAT(hotel.hotel_url,'?aid=*******'))
            ELSE
                CONCAT(hotel.hotel_url,'http://www.example.com/?aid=*******')

            END)
            as hotel_url"))
        ->where('hotel.hotel_id',$hotel_id)
        ->get();
    return view('hotel.hotelPage', ['hotels' => $hotels]);
}
```

and when I load the view

```
@foreach($hotels->comments as $comment) {{$comment->body}} @endforeach
```

I get the error "Property [comments] does not exist on this collection instance./ / /hotelPage.blade.php"

Please help, I am using laravel 5.4

Comment: Your relationship should be `$this->hasMany(Comments::class, 'hotel_id', 'hotel_id')`

Comment: Thanks, A Million @Sandeesh!!